# How to return mongoose model data as array in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ecmascript-6

I have a mongo model, CameraInfo, I need all its data. Been looking around and see functions that does not make sense, to me. I'm new to mongo. I guess using Frameworks hide all the complexities from me.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Mongoose Model
let CameraInfoSchema = mongoose.model('CameraInfo', {
  name: {
    type: String
  },
  ipAddress: {
    type: String
  }
})

// Data to create new schema is not shown.

// Get Camera Model
const CameraInfo = mongoose.model('CameraInfo');

// Return data as array
CameraInfo.find({}, {limit:10}).toArray((err, data) => {
   console.log(data);
})
```

Error I got in my terminal is:

> TypeError: CameraInfo.find(...).toArray is not a function

Answer (score 0):

> The toArray function exists on the Cursor class from the Native
>   MongoDB NodeJS driver check reference [node-mongodb-native](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#toarray)

If you are using mongoose then you can convert it in your callback function

Ex:

```
CameraInfo.find({}, {limit:10},function(err, data){
   console.log(data);
})
```